# Рандомный вывод последних товаров

Tags: select, случайные-числа

```
SELECT `product_id` AS product_id, `name_ru-RU` AS product_name, `alias_ru-RU` AS alias
FROM `al9rm_jshopping_products` ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 3
```

Нужно вывести последние товары в рандом, типа

```
SELECT MAX `product_id` ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 3
```

Comment: ну и? в чем проблема то?

Comment: Верхний запрос - это вывод в рандоме товаров. Нижний - вывод последних 3-х товаров по id (если не ошибаюсь). Как их объединить?